# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' (Python)

Tags: python, stack, rpn

I'm trying to implement stack operations:

If I use a list in `def rpn` itself to store the values and use this list with append and pop it work but as soon as I implement the push and pop and use `self.stack` as storage it's throwing this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File> "C:\Users\donut\Downloads\Stack (1).py", line 88, in module
    print(test.rpn("7 7.8 77 + 2.3 9 + * 222 + *"))  
File "C:\Users\donut\Downloads\Stack (1).py", line 61, in upn
    erg = self.operatoren[el](zahl1, zahl2)   
File "C:\Users\donut\Downloads\Stack (1).py", line 5, in <lambda>
    "+": (lambda a, b: a + b), 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Similar questions here didn't help me.

```py
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.operatoren = {
            "+": (lambda a, b: a + b),
            "-": (lambda a, b: a - b),
            "*": (lambda a, b: a * b),
            "/": (lambda a, b: a / b)
        }

    def push(self, x):
        self.stack.append(x)

    def top(self):
        return self.stack[-1]

    def pop(self):
        self.stack.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self.stack

    def size(self):
        return len(self.stack)

    def rpn(self, expression):
        elemente = expression.split()

        for el in elemente:
            if el in self.operatoren:
                zahl2 = self.pop()
                zahl1 = self.pop()
                erg = self.operatoren[el](zahl1, zahl2)
                self.push(erg)
            else:
                self.push(float(el))

        return self.pop()

test = Stack()

print(test.rpn("7 7.8 77 + 2.3 9 + * 222 + *"))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Ok, your `pop()` method doesn't return what it pops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right.

Comment: Ok, this was a good question. You posted all your code along with a test case for it. You also responded quickly with the full error traceback. The only slight improvement could have been to add your expected output.